# Sender: UIImageView !== UIImageView within CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to get a UIImagePicker to display and image within a CollectionViewCell. The func code is broken where sender is suppose to be equal (==) to UIImageView.

I have reworked the code through the debugger several times and have tried to call the cell through the visibleCells function to no avail.

```swift
//Code for upload func
@objc func uploadPhoto(_ sender: UIImageView) {
        let uploadPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        uploadPicker.delegate = self
        for cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells {
            if let uploadCell = cell as? UploadImageCell {
                print("Pickle Rick and \(uploadCell.imageContainer) and \(sender)")
                if uploadCell.imageContainer == sender {
                    selectedCell = uploadCell
                    print("This code works, \(String(describing: selectedCell))")
                } else {
                    print("code failed at if let")
                }
            }
        }
        present(uploadPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

// Code for CollectionView
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: imageCellId, for: indexPath) as! UploadImageCell
            //let imageOption = ImageOption(rawValue: indexPath.row)
            //cell.imageContainer.image = imageOption?.icon()
            cell.imageContainer.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(uploadPhoto(_:))))
            return cell
        }
/* other sections use different cells*/
}

//code for CollectionViewCell

class UploadImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // Mark: -  Properties

    weak var ep: EditProfileController?

    let imageContainer: UIImageView = {
        let imageContainer = UIImageView()
        imageContainer.clipsToBounds = true
        imageContainer.backgroundColor = .blue
        imageContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageContainer
    }()

    let uploadButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Upload Image", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: button.frame.width, height: 2)
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white

        addSubview(imageContainer)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                imageContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                imageContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.9),
                imageContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor)
        ])

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

The expected result is for the picker image to be displayed in the CollectionViewCell.imageContainer. My debugger always prints "code failed at if let" and at no point has collectionView.reloadData shown a different image after the view loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector for a tap gesture (or any gesture recognizer) must have the actual gesture recognizer as the only argument to the method. So you need to change:

```
@objc func uploadPhoto(_ sender: UIImageView) {
```

to:

```
@objc func uploadPhoto(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
```

Then you can get the image view from the gesture's `view` property.

```
@objc func uploadPhoto(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let imageView = sender.view as? UIImageView { else return }

    let uploadPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    uploadPicker.delegate = self
    for cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells {
        if let uploadCell = cell as? UploadImageCell {
            print("Pickle Rick and \(uploadCell.imageContainer) and \(sender)")
            if uploadCell.imageContainer == imageView {
                selectedCell = uploadCell
                print("This code works, \(String(describing: selectedCell))")
            } else {
                print("code failed at if let")
            }
        }
    }
    present(uploadPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much. My problem now is that if I give my imageContainer a default value it doesn't change once a select an image from the picker.

Comment: Have you implemented UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods?